# Why does extruding a surface affect my edged bevels?

Tags: bevel, extrude

If I extrude a surface like this, my edged bevels are fine:

[image]

If I also go negative on the Z, the bevel is still okay:
[image]

But if I go SLIGHTLY above the surface, the edged bevels dissappear:

[image]

What can I do to extrude the surface just a little bit whilst keeping my bevels consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Clamp Overlap* option of the *Bevel* modifier is probably enabled, it prevents the faces interesections: With a very short extrusion the intersections comes very quick and prevent any bevel.

To fix that you can bevel manually (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) or you can choose *Limit Method > Weight* in the modifier and choose a different *Bevel Weight* for the different edges of your cube:

[image]